# MySQL subquery IN multiple values

Tags: mysql, semi-join

I have 2 tables :

**Table reports**

```
id   |  name
-------------
1    |  test 1
2    |  test 2
3    |  test 3
```

**Table reports_access**

```
id_table  |   group_id
-----------------------
1         |   1
1         |   2
1         |   3
1         |   4
2         |   1
2         |   2
```

I need to access reports depending on **group_id** of the logged user, a user belongs to multiple groups.

I tried :

```
SELECT reports.*
    FROM reports
WHERE (
    SELECT group_id 
        FROM reports_access AS repacc 
        WHERE repacc.id_table = reports.id
    ) IN (1, 3)
```

I got this error :

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

I can't understand if I can do what I want using one request, because I need to test if an array belongs to other array.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Does `(1, 3)` in the subquery represent a user id or a group_id? Either way I think you want a `join` + a `where` not a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
 SELECT reports.*
        FROM reports
    WHERE id in (
        SELECT repacc.id_table 
            FROM reports_access   
           where group_id
        IN (1, 3) )
```

Comment: This correctly implements a semi-join. The other answers (so far) result in duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `JOIN` ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
FROM reports r 
INNER JOIN reports_access ra 
on ra.id_table=r.id 
where ra.group_id in (1,3)
```